# CSS centering an inline element with background color

Tags: html, css, text, inline

I've been trying to get a block of text centered horizontally and vertically within a div of fixed height and width. I also want the text to have a semi transparent black background on it, and for it to be able to stretch onto 2 lines if possible.

The problem I'm having is that the line is not being centered vertically, and the black background behind the text is doing strange things on the beginning of the new line.

The code I've currently got is this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="description">
    <span>Welcome to the world of beautiful design, technology and music.</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.description {
    width: 645px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
div.description span {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 28px;
    line-height: 60px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

I'm looking to imitate this kind of look http://grab.by/fwNe without having to use any strange javascript hacks to break it into 2 lines.

Thanks,
Charlie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a most elegant way, use `display:table-cell;`

The css would be

```
div.description {
    width: 645px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    display:table-cell; 
    vertical-align : middle;
}
div.description span {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 28px;
    line-height: 60px;
    padding: 10px;
}​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thujeevan/EPYAn/)**

Comment: Thanks but do you know if there's a way to fix the lack of padding on the element when it's broken into 2 lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use (or mimic) a table to allow the use of `vertical-align: middle;`. http://jsfiddle.net/LcBbc/

Answer (score 0):

You can specify margin-top and margin-left in terms of percentage values w.r.t the height and width of the window, in div.description.

E.g. 
Replace

```
margin: 0 auto
```

with

```
margin-top: 10%;
margin-left: 20%;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center a div vertically and horizontally, the best way would be using absolute positioning in CSS as such:

```
<div class="description_container">
    <div class="description">
        Welcome to the world of beautiful design, technology and music.
    </div>
</body>
```

And then the CSS

```
.description_container {
    position: relative;
} 
.description {
    width: 640px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -320px; /* half the width of this div */
    margin-top: -100px; /* half the height of this div */
}
```

Now we've created a div with fixed width and height and positioned it vertically and horizontally.

However, you want to be able to wrap on more than 1 line, therefore, we DON'T know what the height of the div is. I would use JS to find the height of the div and then change the values in the CSS accordingly, I wouldn't know how to do it with only CSS - will take a look and let you know.

As for the background, I think it is best to use a semi-transparent png that tiles. I find it's compatibility being much wider than straight within CSS (with IE6 the only browser that doesn't accept it). So it's best to create a 5 x 5px image in Photoshop with whatever transparency you want and export it as PNG-64 and you're gold.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to "center in the unknown" which I find really interesting: http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/ag5ea/

The HTML:

```
<div class="description">
    <span>
        Welcome to the world of beautiful design,<br />
        technology and music.
    </span>
</div>​
```

The CSS:

```
.description {
    width: 645px; height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.description:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    margin-right: -0.25em;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.description span {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I wish I had come up with this technique on my own, but I actually found out about it at css-tricks.com. Here's that link: http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/
    ​